# Pandas: Group by and aggregation with function

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that I have a dataframe with the following values:

```
    name     start    end     description
0    ag       20       30       None
1    bgb      21       111      'a'
2    cdd      31       101      None
3    bgb      17       19       'Bla'
4    ag       20       22       None
```

I want to `groupby` name and then get average of (`end`-`start`) values.

I can use `mean` (`df.groupby(['name'], as_index=False).mean()`)

but how can I give the mean function the subtraction of two columns (last - first) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract column and then grouping by column `df['name']`:

```
df1 = df['end'].sub(df['start']).groupby(df['name']).mean().reset_index(name='diff')
print (df1)
 name  diff
0   ag     6
1  bgb    46
2  cdd    70
```

Another idea with new column `diff`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(diff = df['end'].sub(df['start']))
         .groupby('name', as_index=False)['diff']
         .mean())
print (df1)
  name  diff
0   ag     6
1  bgb    46
2  cdd    70
```